# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':_:detachedConfiguration1' when using node plugin on gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-node-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Java and npm Builds Using Gradle Kotlin DSL. 
I was going through the example [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-java-and-npm-builds-using-gradle) article and [github](https://github.com/xword/java-npm-gradle-integration-example/tree/master/gradle-kotlin-dsl) example code.

I'm in `npm-app` project folder and running the command `gradle npm_run_build`.

> $ gradle npm_run_build
>
> > Task :npm-app:nodeSetup FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':npm-app:nodeSetup'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':npm-app:detachedConfiguration1'.
>   >     Could not find org.nodejs:node:10.14.1.
>   >        Searched in the following locations:
>   >          - https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.14.1/ivy.xml
>   >        Required by:
>   >            project :npm-app
>   >     BUILD FAILED in 810ms
>   >     1 actionable task: 1 executed

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

try switching your node plugin:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "1.5.3"
}
```